# total count of rows that a date falls between two dates

Tags: google-sheets

I have a start date and an end date in each row and I want to count the number of rows (total count) that fall on a specific date.

I tried this:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2, ">="&$A$2:$A, D2, "<="&$B$2:$B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(C$2:C$24, ">="&DateValue(F2), B$2:B$24, "<="&DateValue(F2))
```